# How to resize widgets on a window when the application is running?

Tags: qt4

I have an application that contains more widgets - a QGRaphicsView widget and 2 QListView widgets.

How can I make these widgets resizable  while the application is running? That is drag up and down, left or right from the widgets' margins and it gets re-sized. I did some research and apparently dock widgets can be re-sized without problems. But is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets should be contained within layouts which will cause them to resize themselves when the parent window is resized. You can allow two widgets to be resized within a space that they share using splitters. Without more detail, it's difficult to recommend anything further.

Comment: I just want to have it like in Qt Creator where the user can drag the project widget to left and/or to right resizing it and the widget where the code is written. Although there dock widgets are used. But I would like to have the same functionality without the dock widgets.